# PHP - Idea to Increase Performance to avoid some if-clauses

Tags: php, html, css, performance, navigation

**Hey** guys!

At the moment, I am writing a class for generating an Navigationbar for each page, that I have to change only this php script.

I am producing the code with a static function. The first parameter has to be the rest of the absolute URL (bad description...I don't know how to describe :( ) from where the function is called.

So currently, I am using if-clauses, to check whether the subsequent listitem should be active (visually) or not. Only if there is an equality between the absolute path for the navigation entry and the composition of the absolute path and the given filepath paramter, the script will echo the 'active' css class. Otherwise it won't.

The verification uses an associative array to get the absolute filepath of the respective html-file.

Here's an example code shred, I hope it'll be clearer then, because my declaration isn't pretty good and I'm from Germany resulting possibly bad english :)

```
echo "<ul class='dropdown-menu'>\n";
  if($use.$filepath == $urls['netOv']){
    echo "<li class='active'>";
  }else{
    echo "<li>";
  }
   echo "<a href='" . $urls['netOv'] . "'>Overview</a></li>\n";


  if($use.$filepath == $urls['netFut']){
    echo "<li class='active'>";
  }else {
    echo "<li>";
   }
  echo "<a href='" . $urls['netFut'] . "'>Functions</a></li>\n";
```

(The '$urls' is the array, I've spoken from, in which the absolute paths are deposited)

I don't really know whether this is the best solution for my problem, because the are many if-clauses, for each menu entry one.

This is very unperformant, isn't it?

Thanks for **help** in advance

Comment: Are you using a database like mysql?

Comment: No, I don't use it for the navigationbar, because the MySQL-server has to catch so many requets, I wouldn't like to do a MySQL query for each time the a file is called

Comment: This way to do is not maintainable, i advise you to use a templating engine like twig or smarty if you want to optimise performance, if you dont want to use a sql database, you should at least make php functions...

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of echoing those many times, you can take a variable to which u add the stuff inside the if else conditions. In the end echo the overall contents of that variable. This would result in a better performance than existing, if performance is what u r looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do more PHP pre-processing. It's a good practice to to limit the amount of logic implemented directly in the template and stick to the simplest.

There are **many** ways to implement that, but a simple one that is compatible with your code would be to store it all in an array and loop through it in your template.

```
<?php
// I'm not sure whether `$urls` contains URLs from other pages than the menu and I'll assume that it's the case. Let's create a separate array for menu URLs:
$menuItems = array(
    $urls['netOv'] => array(
        'label' => 'Overview',
        'class' => '',
    ),
    $urls['netFut'] => array(
        'label' => 'Functions',
        'class' => '',
    ),
);

// Let's set the current active page
if (!empty($menuItems[$use.$filepath])) {
    $menuUrls[$use.$filepath]['class'] = ' class="active"';
}

// Now let's print it all
foreach ($menuItems as $menuUrl => $menuItem) {
    echo '<li' . $menuItem['class'] . '><a href="' . $menuUrl . '">' . $menuItem['label'] . '</a></li>';
}
```

That way, if you need to add more menus in the future, just add them to the `$menuItems` array. As you can see, I used only one `if` statement :)

Answer (score 0):

**THANKS** to all of you!

I've found a solution now. It's the most performant, but with JavaScript.
The php script prints only the html of the navigation, so without 'echos', just pure html as php-function.

On each site there is a php-generated JavaScript, adding the class to the current file, which is open.

For me, this solution is satisfactory. People who have turned JavaScript off don't have to see which site is enabled anyway :)

**Thanks** again for **helping**. I will keep the solutions in mind and there will be another situation for use soon...